# Why doesn't `print`ed output on the same line appear between `time.sleep` calls?

Tags: python

So I'm having some trouble with Python. I have a code that is:

```
import time

def printChat(string, sleepTime):
    for a in string:
        print (a, end="")
        time.sleep(sleepTime)
    print()
```

When I do printChat("Hello", 0.1) it should print a letter and wait 0.1 seconds and then print the next one, but instead, it waits 0.5 seconds (as '**hello**' is 5 characters long) and then prints hello all of a sudden. Any idea why that is?

Comment: You need to flush

Comment: See [How to flush output of Python print?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/230751/35070).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to flush output of Python print?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-python-print)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use:

```
        print (a, end="", flush=True)
```

Because console output is line-buffered.

Comment: Can you provide a source to the statement that console output is buffered? Isn't it stdout that's a buffered stream, no matter whether it goes to console or file?

Comment: @phihag If it's a file, then `'\n'` won't flush the buffer. Only console is line-buffered.

Comment: Thanks, it is now working fine. I'll accept the answer as soon as I can.