# Python 3.7.1 try except block happening in wrong order in command line

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, try-except

I'm a beginner and working on a very basic skill set.

I'm making a simple text game in command line for windows, and have a function that lets users read the most recent statement, and skip it by causing a KeyboardInterrupt like with Ctrl-C.

```
from time import sleep
def wait(seconds):
    try:
        sleep(seconds)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    return
```

the issue arises when I want to print something and not have a newline afterwards. In that case, the wait() function will execute before the print() function

```
# functions properly, but has unwanted newline
print("test", end='test\n')
wait(3)
# in windows CMD, wait() executes before print()
print("test", end='test')
wait(3)
```

I know there are ways around this like using TKinter, but I want to know why this happens, not how to avoid it entirely.

EDIT: I kept searching and found the issue wasn't the try except block, but sleep():
[Error with Print and Sleep in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49350624/error-with-print-and-sleep-in-python)
copy of the answer:

You should use:

```
print (a, end="", flush=True)
```

Because console output is line-buffered.

Comment: I can't replicate this with your example. With both ways, `\n` and no `\n` it executes in the expected order, print then wait, for me.

Comment: I was reading and was about to answer, then saw that you'd already found the answer :). Since you figured it out, you should post an answer to your question; [it's very much allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)! Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with your answer. You should use:

```
print(a, end="", flush=True)
```

because console output is line-buffered.